# How do I remove a class from a div in a modal content box when it has been loaded after the page loads?

Tags: jquery

How do I remove a class from a div in a modal content box when it has been loaded after the page loads? I'm just trying to create a little spinner while a form is submitted VIA AJAX.

Here is the div:

```
<div id="modal-loading" class="hidden"><div id="modal-loading-spinner"></div></div>
```

here is the jQuery:

```
// START:: generic modal form submit
$('#modal').on('submit', 'form[data-async]', function(e) {

    $('#modal-loading').removeClass('hidden');

    var myclass = $(this).attr('class');
    if(myclass == 'form form-surcharge-edit'){
        collapseModal = 1;
    }

    var $form = $(this);
    var enctype = $form.attr('enctype');
    var formData = $form.serialize();

    console.log('form submitted data = ' + formData);

    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        dataType  : "json",

        success: function(data, status) {

            $('#modal-loading').addClass('hidden');

            if(status == 'success'){

                $("#form").css("display","none");
                $('#modal #formMessage').html(data.msg).removeClass('hidden').addClass(data.class);

            }else if(status == 'error'){

                $("#formMessage").html(data);

            }

        },

        error: function(data){
            $('#modal-loading').addClass('hidden');
            //this would be a 404 error!
        },

    });

    e.preventDefault();

});
// END:: generic modal form submit
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the hidden div not existing when the page is initially rendered. But not sure how to show/hide the element in the jQuery.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use things like $('#modal #formMessage').  Your id's should always be unique so just call that id.  If you are trying to address multiple id at once, then put a comma between them.  As far as adding/removing a class, your removeClass('hidden').addClass(data.class) are both correct.

Comment: To show/hide in jquery, use .show() and .hide().